# How to call a TypeScript function in an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have a TypeScript file named `listeners.ts` that defines event listeners like this:

```
export function TimeField_OnChange () {
  // ...
}
```

There is an `index.html` in which I want to use this function like this (**which doesn't work**):

```
document.getElementById("timeFieldCheckBox").addEventListener("change", TimeField_OnChange);
```

The browsers JavaScript engine cannot find the function. How do I reference it correctly?

Comment: When you use `export` all variables are scoped inside IIFE to prevent them bleeding to global scope. So they will not be available on HTML page. You can create a global variable and assign this variable to it to access on HTML but you should not do it. Ideally this operation should be a part of some component and it should be there.

Comment: @Rajesh: So what would be a reasonable solution in your opinion?

Comment: Ideally, this should be a part of component and you should do this operation there. If I assume correct, there is a field that accepts time and you wish to have a checkbox that enable/disable this input field on selection of this field. or something like this.

Comment: By component you mean the HTML file? The thing is that I also need the function in other TypeScript files and I don't want to repeat the code.

Comment: When you say you are using TS, I assumed, you are using React/Angular. If yes, you will have a Component/Directive. If not, you can just create a global variable and use it from there as it will be faster

Comment: No Angular or React here.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example shows how you can add event listeners to dom elements, without having any code in index.html. The listener and the handler are inside two different modules.

**utils.ts**

```
export function TimeField_OnChange (e:Event) {
   // your event handler here
}
```

**main.ts**

```
import TimeField_OnChange from "./utils";

export function initPage () {
    // here you add listeners to dom elements
    let box = document.getElementById("timeFieldCheckBox");
    box.addEventListener("change", (e:Event) => TimeField_OnChange(e));
  }
}
// this is the starting point of your app
initPage();
```

**bundling**

Now you have to bundle your `*.ts` files into one `main.js` file using webpack. You need webpack because otherwise `import` and `export` won't work.

You can also bundle just using `tsc` but then you have to leave out `import` and `export`. It will still work, and you can still have your handler in a different .ts file. The only difference with webpack is that now your TimeField_OnChange and initPage functions will be in the global scope.

**index.html**

The html file only contains a link to the main.js file.

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: But I would like to use the function in other TypeScript modules too.

Comment: Then you have to import the module before you can use it, see edit.

Comment: But if I put the function into a module, I can no longer reference it in my HTML file, can I?

Comment: If you have a `<script>` tag in your HTML that isn't part of your module build process, then you COULD make your function available to the global window by using: `window.TimeField_OnChange = ...`. Then you can call it from anywhere you want. Of course, the whole idea of modules is that you don't pollute the global scope. It would be better not to have any javascript in your HTML file. Why do you need that?

Comment: Thank you for another suggestion. The purpose is not to duplicate code. The function is used as an event listener, but also somewhere else when the controls are initialized. I solved it by attaching the event listener in the `main.ts` file (not in any function, but right at the beginning of the file), which is the first one included into index.html by the module loader (require.js).

Comment: OK, but then it should be easy. You can add the Event Listeners when your app is initialised and has access to all the modules. The `addEventListener()` code doesn't have to be outside of a function or a class, and it doesn't need to be in index.html. You can add listeners to DOM elements at any point in your app that you want. I will edit the answer :)